# "netstat -p tcp" on my mac displays an unknown connection to stackoverflow.co.http

Tags: mac

The following is the output of "netstat -p tcp" on my mac.

```
tcp4       0      0  192.168.0.100.63515    17.172.232.11.5223     ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.0.100.63514    stackoverflow.co.http  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.0.100.63510    17.110.228.142.5223    ESTABLISHED
```

I "whois"ed the 1st and 3rd ip and they belong to Apple.
I did not visit stack overflow since morning and also my browsers (safari and chrome) were not running in background, then what is stack overflow.co.http doing in my network.
I do not have any program except for a terminal and preview for ibook running when i checked the netstat connection list.
It is in ESTABLISHED state as you can see above.
Do i have an unknown program running in background that is creating a connection to stackoverflow ? If anyone happen to know any thing about this please share the information
Also is there any way I can see which program has established a connection with stackoverflow.co.http.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have following

```
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.3.54402      stackoverflow.co.https ESTABLISHED
```

But when I turn off my Browser (Quit) that is no longer there.

To see who is using what run

```
lsof -i -P
```

Comment: Even i had my browsers exited (Command-q) but the connection would still show up.

Comment: run lsof -i -P
 to see who is using what connection

Comment: `lsof -i:https -P` will limit the display to https connections (or more accurately, those on port 443), so you won't have as much to looks through.

Comment: @GordonDavisson a nice one :) found multiple deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:443 suckers !